# Enlarge part of image where mouse pointing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a grid with image label that looks like this:

```
<Grid Height="180" Width="180" Grid.Column="2">
        <Image Height="180" Width="180" Source="{Binding Result}">
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="st2" CenterX="90" CenterY="90" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
            </Image.LayoutTransform>
            <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="st2"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                         To="3.0" Duration="0:0:0" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="st2"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                         To="3.0" Duration="0:0:0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeave">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="st2"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                         To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="st2"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                         To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
```

I presented how it works on this picture:

[image]

Anywhere i point my mouse on `KMM` image, it will enlarge the same part of the image. For example, when i point my mouse bottom of the image, it still enlarge the same, top left part of this image (as i show below):

[image]

How to edit my code to enlarge my image anywhere where my mouse point? I can use code behind of my `xaml` file (`xaml.cs`). I only want it to work

Comment: @dymanoid i make some edits. In short, i want to enlarge the part of the image anywhere i point on this image. For now, anywhere i point by my mouse it still enlarge the same part of the image. I want to enlarge part of the image where mouse pointing on this specifig image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using built-in scaling transform makes the scaling of the target image easier, the mouse position tracking isn't that easy.

I would suggest you to use a viewbox of an `ImageBrush` to display your zoomed image. You can set the view box of the `ImageBrush` to show the needed portion of your image.

To make the code reusable, create an attached property. For example, like this one:

```
public static class ViewBoxTracking
{
    // Source is an UIElement that will provide the mouse input
    // for calculating of the view box bounds.
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Source", typeof(UIElement), typeof(ViewBoxTracking), new PropertyMetadata(null, SourceChanged));

    public static void SetSource(TileBrush brush, UIElement value) => brush.SetValue(SourceProperty, value);

    public static UIElement GetSource(TileBrush brush) => (UIElement)brush.GetValue(SourceProperty);

    private const int ZoomFactor = 3;

    private static void SourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs ea)
    {
        if (ea.NewValue is UIElement source && d is ImageBrush target)
        {
            // When the mouse cursor exits the source element,
            // reset the view box to the 100% zoom;
            // you can remove or change this logic.
            source.MouseLeave += (s, e) => target.Viewbox = new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1);

            // When the mouse hovers over the source object, update the view box.
            source.MouseMove += (s, e) => SourceMouseMove(target, e.GetPosition(source), source.RenderSize);
        }
    }

    private static void SourceMouseMove(ImageBrush target, Point currentPoint, Size sourceSize)
    {
        // The view box width is based on the zoom factor
        double viewBoxWidth = sourceSize.Width / ZoomFactor;
        double viewBoxHeight = sourceSize.Height / ZoomFactor;

        // Calculate the bounds for the view box - at first, in absolute coordinates.
        double x = Math.Max(0, currentPoint.X - viewBoxWidth / 2);
        double y = Math.Max(0, currentPoint.Y - viewBoxHeight / 2);
        if (x + viewBoxWidth > sourceSize.Width)
        {
            x = sourceSize.Width - viewBoxWidth;
        }

        if (y + viewBoxHeight > sourceSize.Height)
        {
            y = sourceSize.Height - viewBoxHeight;
        }

        // Now, make the coordinates relative.
        x /= sourceSize.Width;
        y /= sourceSize.Height;

        // Set the new view box to the target image brush.
        target.Viewbox = new Rect(x, y, 1d / ZoomFactor, 1d / ZoomFactor);
    }
}
```

And here is an example how to use the new attached property in XAML:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="2">
    <Grid Height="180" Width="180">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding YourImage}" ViewboxUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox" 
                        local:ViewBoxTracking.Source="{Binding ElementName=MainImage}" />
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>

    <Image x:Name="MainImage" Height="180" Width="180" Source="{Binding YourImage}" />

</UniformGrid>
```

`local` is the XAML namespace representing your namespace where you place the attached property, something like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"`.

Comment: That looks awesome. In few hours i will check it in my solution. Thanks